# Prepopulating dropdownlist without the "Please select.." an improvement to user experience?

Tags: user-experience

We have a shopping cart site that will accept credit card as payment, (Discover, Visa, Master, Amex) and my understanding is if credit card type is a required field anyway, is there a reason we want to still include the "Please select one.." as the default selectable option in the dropdownlist? What is inconvenient or inappropriate to pre-populate the dropdown with say "Discover" as the default choice here?

We also have the expiration month/year for the credit card as input from user fields, is it not a good idea to exclude those months that will not be valid anyway, when user selected the year as current year? For example, on 2/1/2012, user entered their credit card expiration info, if user indicated their credit card expiration year is 2012, we have the script to exclude January from the dropdown, so we don't need to inform user they need to correct their error before allowing them to move forward if they selected January as the expiration month.

Would leaving those 3 fields (Credit card type, expiration month, expiration year) with default or invalid data provide a better experience to user? Would pre-populating those required fields provide any worse user experience than leaving those fields blank? Is it not a good idea to build a Web site to minimize the chance of letting user make mistake? Or basically the requirement from a developer's standpoint is different than those from the business world?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1** 
Would it be possible to automatically determine the credit card type from the number?  Then the user does not have to enter any credit card type.  Seems Apple does this on their website.

**Question 2** 
I think it is appropriate not to allow the user the opportunity for mistake.  So yes, I would remove non-valid months from the list.

**Question 3**
I think it's a better user experience to pre-populate with invalid data.  In the scenario that the user does not make any choices, you can catch this and provide an appropriate error message.  If you pre-populate with valid data, then you will not be able to distinguish the case where the user entered "January 1st" for example, from the case that they simply did not fill out the form.  I think it is always a good idea to minimize the chance for mistakes.  This is the core of a good user experience.